# Cannot boot Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10

Tags: 12.04, boot

I cannot get Ubuntu to boot or run on my gaming build, while Windows 7 runs fine. 12.04 boots to desktop on live disc and says I have a network connection, but Firefox won't do anything but lock up. Then the whole OS locks up, making it unusable. 12.10 won't even boot I get an error saying kvm is disabled by bios. I don't even own a kvm. If I turn Intel Virtualization on 12.10 just freezes during the Ubuntu loading screen. I have tried resetting my bios to the defaults and tried booting with the option nomodeset, same results as before. I want to install Ubuntu to an SSD I had laying around for a dual boot.

My system specs:

Core I5 2500K @ 4.5Ghz

8 Gigs of Corsair XMS3 DDR3 1600

Asus P8Z68 V-Pro/Gen3

Sapphire Radeon HD 6970 (2 Gig Model)

Power supply Antec 750 Watt High Current Gamer